# Unable to append a list with numpy values

Tags: python, list, numpy

I want to calculate the average vector length from a file that contains coordinates. Ultimately I want to store `vector_length` as a list called `pair_length`. I will calculate the average of the `pair_length` list later on in my program using `average()` function. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
from numpy import sqrt
from itertools import islice
from statistics import mean

data = open("coords.txt","r")

def average():
    return mean()

pair_length = []

for line in islice(data, 1, None): #the first line is the number of pairs
    fields = line.split("   ")
    pair_num = int(fields[0]) #the first field is the pair number
    x_cord = float(fields[1]) #x-coordinate
    y_cord = float(fields[2]) #y-coordinate
    vector_length = sqrt(x_cord**2 + y_cord**2) #vector length (all numbers in the coords.txt file are real and positive)
    vector_length.append(pair_length)
```

I receive the error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: `pair_length.append(vector_length)` instead of `vector_length.append(pair_length)`

Comment: why on earth are you using `numpy.sqrt`? use `math.sqrt` if you aren't using numpy for anything else. In any case, either square root function will return a single number in this case. You cannot append to a `float`  (or in the numpy version, a `numpy.float64`)... did you mean `pair_length.append(vector_length)`???

Comment: Please provide the entire error. What do/don't you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `vector_length` stores a `float` value, and hence append operation won't work with it.
Append operation works with lists, in python.

So, what we can do is:

Instead of

```py
vector_length.append(pair_length)
```

We can do as follows:

```py
pair_length.append(vector_length)
```

Hope this works.